# why my return value is giving value of y after second if statement fails? if i skip else in if?

Tags: c, function, if-statement

program is to check if `x,y` is greater then 0 and less then `n-1` using function if this statement fails `if((y>0) && (y<(n-1)))` then it is returning value of y, I forgot to put else and it worked but returned value of y instead.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int check(int x, int y, int n) {
  if ((x > 0) && (x < (n - 1))) {
    if ((y > 0) && (y < (n - 1))) {
      return 1;
    }
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

int main(void) {
  int x, y, n;
  printf("enter 3 numbers:");
  scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &n);
  printf("%d", check(x, y, n));
  return 0;
}
```

input: 11 12 13
output:12

Comment: not all code paths in `check` return a value

Comment: If you create a function with a non-`void` return value and forget to use `return` statements in all branches of the control flow, then this is undefined behavior. You will get the value that happens to be in the register or on the stack where the return value is expected as defined by your system's calling conventions. A decent compiler should print a warning about a missing `return`.

Comment: Just remove the `else` block and `return 0;` at the end of your function. Otherwise, you'll need another `else` block *inside* the outermost `if`.

Comment: @Bodo In C, just reaching end of non-void function without `return` statement doesn't invoke undefined behavior. Using the value "returned" without `return` statement invokes undefined behavior.